# How to change type of column in pandas without column name?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a problem with a data type.

Please assumed that here is my sample data frame.

```
class1 class2 docid
 A123   08/9   X123
 A123   08/1   X123
 A124   08/1   X124
 A124   08/2   X124
 A125   08/3   X125
```

I have merged class1 and class2 then named as class3

```
  class3     docid
 A123,08/9   X123
 A123,08/1   X123
 A124,08/1   X124
 A124,08/2   X124
 A125,08/3   X125
```

and then make a matrix by get_dummies

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.docid).sort_index(level=0).max(level=[0,1])
df1
```

and get the results like this

```
class3     X123 X124 X125
A123,08/9   1    0    0
A123,08/1   1    0    0
A124,08/1   0    1    0
A124,08/2   0    1    0
A125,08/3.  0    0    1
```

and then I have dropped the class3 then transposed this matrix to calculate the Jaccard similarity by docid

```
df1_new = df1.drop(['class3'], axis=1)
df1_new_1 = df1_new.transpose()
df1_new_1
```

and the results are being like this

```
     0 1 2 3 4 
X123 1 1 0 0 0
X124 0 0 1 1 0
X125 0 0 0 0 1
```

from this result, the column has no name, then I would like to ask how can I change the X123 X124 X125 into 0 1 2 or only change the datatype from string to int? because, when I use this result to calculate the Jaccard similarity, it's appeared

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X123'
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is just to change the str index to int , you can use

```
df1_new_1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

if you want to keep the values from string, you can use

```
df1_new_1.index.str.extract(r'\d+')
```

Out:

```
Int64Index([123, 124, 125], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! i forgot to think about that T T